# Python : Unable to import TA-lib while it shows in the pip list

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, ta-lib

I believe I have successfully install TA-lib in Ubuntu VM (it is using ARM64) as when I type `pip list`, it shows in my python 3.8 packages together with all other modules. Unfortunatley, when I call `import talib`, an error as below exists

```
>>> import talib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/talib/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from ._ta_lib import (
ImportError: libta_lib.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWWno.png

I also use the command `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but the same error is shown.

The talib folders as per screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeDTX.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG8He.png

**It is a problem specific to ARM64 or AArch64 as I manage to install talib in X64. I successfully installed talib in X64 with the same Ubuntu version , the only difference is only it is in X64**

Both ARM64 and X64 talib has the `libta_lib.so.0` in `./ta-lib/src/.libs/libta_lib.so.0`

Comment: Do you have `libta_lib.so.0` file in `/usr/local/lib` ?

Comment: @truf No. It does not have the `libta_lib.so.0` file in `/usr/local/lib`. However, it also doe snot have the file in X64 that I have installed talib successfully. Not just in ARM64

Comment: @truf both X64 and ARM64 has the file at `./ta-lib/src/.libs/libta_lib.so.0`

Comment: Then go to the `./ta-lib` and perform `sudo make install`. Notice where `libta_lib.so.0` is copied from `./ta-lib/src/.libs/`. It will be printed in console window. Then doublecheck if the library is really there. Use that folder in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is specific to ARM/Aarch64 Virtual Machine in Ubuntu 20.04.
In your directory of Ubuntu, type

`sudo ldconfig`

To confirm if TA-lib able to import with error, reboot your VM.
This is the simplest way to fix the issue permanently without `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Answer (score 0):

It's normal, you shouldn't use pip to install python3 libraries, use pip3 instead, pip is for python2. Probably what happened is that you installed ta-lib for python2(that use pip) instead of python3(that use pip3).

Please, let us know if you still have problem after you executing the following command in a shell:

```
pip3 install ta-lib
```

Comment: I can staright away `pip3 install ta-lib` or shall I uninstall first?

Comment: same error still exist. As show in teh screenshot, talib is already in the python 3.8 site package and I do not have python 2.7

Comment: On sorry I didn't see the screenshot, and anyway yes, you could go straight away with 'pip3 install', but as the error persist it isn't pip the problem. I'll take a look to the various screenshots and if I understand how to solve I tell you

Comment: I just tried to install it on one of my raspberry and it gives me errors during the installation with pip3, I'm starting to think that maybe the library is not supported for ARM64

Comment: It should not the case as Mac laptop is using ARM64 too. I notice Mac ARM64 need some special command but I am on Ubuntu